# Rendering a multi-colored segmented progress bar

Tags: javascript, algorithm, reactjs

Segmented Progress Bar like this:

[image: img]

I'm developing a segmented progress bar in react that will dynamically render up to 15 pill shaped svgs like the one displayed in the picture.
What I'm having trouble with, is the algorithm to render the segments filled with the appropriate colors up to the completed percentage while rendering the remaining pill shapes with the default "empty" color.
Any direction or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: dude, stackoverflow isn't for people to write code for you.  You have to have attempted something, and then people can help you with bugs or tricky bits - you might surprise yourself when you write something, it might work :)

but here is a hint: colors = ['red','yellow','green'];   thisPillColor= completed?  colors[Math.floor(counter/5)]: 'grey';

Comment: @FrazerKirkman, thank you for your comment and your suggestion. I'm honestly not asking anyone to write code for me. The things I'm trying aren't being successful. I just asking for some help with the problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: so the idea with stack overflow is that you post the code you have tried

Comment: we need to be able to see exactly what you are thinking, so we know where to correct it :)

Answer (score 1):

Possible logic in pseudocode:

```
for i = 0 to 14
    ratio = i / 14
    if CurrentValue >= ratio 
       drawPill(i-th position, AppropriateColor[i])  
    else
       drawPill(i-th position, DefaultGrayColor)
```